# Above-the-fold inline styles from SASS generated stylesheet

Tags: hooks

Im currently looking for a solution to make an "above-the-fold" inline stylesheet inside my header. But the clue is, to have it get its content from a .css file that was rendered from SCSS. So in other words, there is no existing stylesheet to hook into via `wp_add_inline_style`

Is there something built-into wordpress to get a result similar to this:

```
<head>
    <style>
    .myselector { 
      height: 500px;
      /* more stuff */
    }
    </style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='mainstyles-css'  href='http://localhost/project/wp-content/themes/project-v2/style.css?ver=4.9.5' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <...more stylesheets potentially...>
</head>
```

Comment: You can hook into [`wp_head`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) and output your code, if necessary.

Comment: Yea, well but how would I make my rendered css to appear there? I can't think of a solution for that, and thats the whole point actually. I cannot use something like ´get_template_part´ cause it only accepts php, does it?

Comment: I am looking for a workflow as well, where you use a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scss/, and it automatically generates above the fold CSS.